# Can't access external controller ActionResults from Identity Register page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to populate a dropdown from a controller action result but is receiving an Error 500 when trying to call the action from Identity Register page.
This is on localhost and my breakpoint isn't getting hit.

Front End (Register.cshtml)

```
   @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
  .Name("products")
  .Placeholder("Select product")
  .DataTextField("Name")
  .DataValueField("CountryId")
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
  .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
  .AutoBind(false)
  .MinLength(3)
  .DataSource(source =>
  {
      source.Read(read =>
      {
          read.Action("GetProducts", "UserDetails");
      })
      .ServerFiltering(true);
  })
    )
```

Controller:

```
[Route("userdetails")]
public partial class UserDetailsController : Controller
{
    public UserDetailsService _userDetailsService;

    public UserDetailsController(UserDetailsService userDetailsService)
    {
        _userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    public ActionResult GetProducts()
    {
        // run synchronously as partials cannot use async
        List<ViewModels.CountriesSelectList> task = _userDetailsService.GetCountriesSelectList();
        var results = task;

        return Json(results);
    }
```

I Have tried changing it from a Get to a Post but the Error changes from 500 to 405, I believe Identity is blocking the calls

I am expecting to get a list of all countries

Comment: 405 means Method Not Allowed. You can't just arbitrarily switch between GET and POST - if you want to support POST you have to set a attribute on your action method to do so. I doubt that will help you anyway. Switch back to GET and then focus on finding the cause of the 500 - it normally indicates that the server crashed, so look for exception messages, logs in your event log etc.

Comment: @ADyson This is happening while developing within Visual Studio not on a server

Comment: Ok so if you are running locally in debug mode you should be able to get some information about the crash even more easily. Does visual studio not throw an exception? Or there might still be something in your event logs